# PySpark : TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable when executing spark.createdataframe()

Tags: python, java, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create a spark data frame from pandas data frame.

```
self.spark= SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = pd.read_csv(fileName, dtype=dtypes)
dfSpark = self.spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

However I am hitting this error while trying to load

**Error details**

```
at C:\Users\tkarthik\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py:720: in createDataFrame
 return super(SparkSession, self).createDataFrame(

at C:\Users\tkarthik\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyspark\sql\pandas\conversion.py:311: in createDataFrame
return self._create_dataframe(data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)

self = <pyspark.sql.session.SparkSession object at 0x000001C958C28BB0>
data = [(202, 'None', 'None', 'None', 1, 'None', ...), (202, 'NP', 'None', 'None', 1, 'None', ...), (202, 'NP', 'None', 'None...', 34, 'None', ...), (39984421, 'AE', '34', 'MT', 34, 'None', ...), (39984423, 'AE', '34', 'MT', 34, 'None', ...), ...]
schema = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', ...]
samplingRatio = None, 
verifySchema = True

def _create_dataframe(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema):
    if isinstance(schema, StructType):
        verify_func = _make_type_verifier(schema) if verifySchema else lambda _: True

        def prepare(obj):
            verify_func(obj)
            return obj
    elif isinstance(schema, DataType):
        dataType = schema
        schema = StructType().add("value", schema)

        verify_func = _make_type_verifier(
            dataType, name="field value") if verifySchema else lambda _: True

        def prepare(obj):
            verify_func(obj)
            return obj,
    else:
        prepare = lambda obj: obj

    # With table ACL enabled, user should not be able to perform rdd operations. Therefore, we
    # only need to handle dataframe from pandas or simple list here using trusted path.
    if self._sc._conf.get(             
      self._jvm.PythonSecurityUtils.SPARK_PYTHON_TO_JVM_TRUSTED_DATA_TRANSFER_ENABLED()) \
            and not isinstance(data, RDD):
E               TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable

 C:\Users\tkarthik\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py:747: TypeError
```

Can someone please help me understand what the issue is and figure out the solution for this?

> Current settings 
> Python = 3.8.10 
> jre version "1.8.0_321" 
> Spark version = 3.1.2 
> hadoop version = 2.7

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully figured out the issue. There were multiple installations of python and they were scattered across the file system.

```
Fix :

 1. Removed all installations of python, java, apache-spark
 2. Cleaned up your directories if they have these package folders.
    Like AppData\Roaming\Python etc
 3. Deleted environmental variables like spark_home, java_howe and any instances of these in path env variable (Like ...Python38\scripts) 

 4. Started a clean installation of apache-spark. [Installation_Steps][1]
 5. Tested a sample code using spark-shell to verify if this is working.
```

Thanks.